# Find Controller DiplayName and Show it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection

i write this code for find controller list in my project .

```
    public IEnumerable<Type> GetControllerDescovery(Assembly assemblies)
    {
        var controllers = assemblies.GetExportedTypes()
                                                    .Where(t => typeof(ControllerBase)
                                                    .IsAssignableFrom(t))
                                                    .Select(t => t).
                                                    ToList();
        return controllers;
    }
```

and it show me this output :

```
"IranNews.Controllers.V1.CategoryController, IranNews, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
"IranNews.Controllers.V1.RoleManagerController, IranNews, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
"IranNews.Controllers.V1.UserController, IranNews, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
"IranNews.Controllers.V1.ValuesController, IranNews, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
```

but i need to get name of contrller from `[Display(Name = "UserManager")]`

and show me this : `UserManager`

how can i do this ?????

Comment: Controllers have no display names. `DisplayName` is an attribute used with models, not controllers. If you check all MVC tutorials you'll see that they start by setting the desired title with `ViewBag.Title` and then render this in the view as the browser title, or a heading. More advanced tutorials may render a model property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i using the web api

Comment: What would you need a display name then? What are you trying to do? In any case, [DisplayName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) is an attribute. You need to call `t.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()` on a type or property to retrieve it and read its value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to create a dynamic permission . I want the names of the menus to appear in the name of the controllers

Comment: I suspect this is a case of [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with X and think that Y is the solution. When that doesn't work, you ask about Y, not X. There are many duplicate questions that show how to retrieve attribute values using reflection, it just doesn't make any sense in this case. `DisplayName` is used on *data objects* and view models to make it easier to render them. It has no use on a controller. It's doesn't affect MVC in any way. It will never appear on a route

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please tell me directly how can I solve it?

Comment: @kianoush did you check my update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
typeof(ControllerBase)
.GetProperties()
.Select(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>())
.Where(x => x != null)
.Select(x => x.Name)
.ToList();
```

**Update:**
Here's a working example:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetExportedTypes()
        .Where(t => typeof(ControllerBase).IsAssignableFrom(t))
        .Select(t => t.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>())
        .Where(x => x != null)
        .Select(x => x.Name)
        .ToList();
```